# How to share value between pipelines in Gitlab

Tags: gitlab-ci

I am trying to implement checkstyle quality gate. This line `if [ -e no_checkstyle_issues.txt ]; then PREVIOUS_ISSUES=$(cat no_checkstyle_issues.txt); else PREVIOUS_ISSUES=99999; fi` always returns `99999`, so I am guessing I am doing something wrong. How can I fetch the `no_checkstyle_issues.txt` artifact from the previous build?

```
checkstyle:
  extends: .test-build-template
  stage: checkstyle
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - "no_checkstyle_issues.txt"
    expire_in: 3 hrs
  script:
    - echo "Running checkstyle stage"
    - gradle checkstyleMain
    # no. of Checkstyle issues from previous commit
    - PREVIOUS_ISSUES=0
    - if [ -e no_checkstyle_issues.txt ]; then PREVIOUS_ISSUES=$(cat no_checkstyle_issues.txt); else PREVIOUS_ISSUES=99999; fi
    - echo "No. of previous checkstyle issues = $PREVIOUS_ISSUES"
    # no. of Checkstyle issues from current commit
    - CURRENT_ISSUES=0
    - for file in $(find . -type f -name 'main.xml'); do CURRENT_ISSUES=$((CURRENT_ISSUES + $(grep -o '<error' $file | wc -l))); done
    - echo "No. of current checkstyle issues = $CURRENT_ISSUES"
    # if CURRENT_ISSUES > PREVIOUS_ISSUES, fail pipeline
    - if [ $CURRENT_ISSUES -gt $PREVIOUS_ISSUES ]; then echo "Checkstyle issues increased. Failing pipeline!"; exit 1; fi
    - mkdir -p artifacts/checkstyle
    - echo $CURRENT_ISSUES > no_checkstyle_issues.txt
    - exit 0
```

Comment: You want to compare against the last build _from the same branch_? What should happen if it's the first build on a new branch?

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain files from previous pipelines in a few ways:

1. From previous pipeline artifacts using [`needs:project:`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#needsproject) (requires Premium subscription)
2. From previous pipeline artifacts using [job artifacts API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/job_artifacts.html#download-a-single-artifact-file-from-specific-tag-or-branch) (requires an API token)
3. From previous pipelines cache, using [`cache:`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#cache) with caching configured to [share caches between jobs on the same branch](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/#share-caches-between-jobs-in-the-same-branch)
4. A home-brew method where you write the logic for uploading and downloading the file

For quality gates, you usually want to compare with watermark to the *default branch* (not the same branch you're on) so that's what I'll do here. But you can change the `ref:` parameter to whatever ref you want to compare with.

```yaml
checkstyle:
  variables:
    RESULTS_FILE: "no_checkstyle_issues.txt"
  needs:
    - project: $CI_PROJECT_PATH
      ref: $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH  # or $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME for the current branch
      artifacts: true

  artifacts:
    paths:
      - $RESULTS_FILE

  script:
    - | 
      if [ -f "$RESULTS_FILE" ]; then
          echo "previous run data found"
          cat "$RESULTS_FILE"
      else
          echo "no previous run data found. (this might be the first run)"
      fi
    # ...
```